# Tide system with two moons

Tags: moons, tides

I have a planet with two moons where one moon exactly rotates the earth at earths speed. Means only one side of the planet can see the moon and the other moon will rotate that earth in 45 days. What will be tide cycle if the earth's diameter and mass is just the normal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The Moon that is tidally locked to Earth will not produce any changing tides. There will still be a tidal bulge in the water but it will remain in the same place, so some areas will have perpetual high tide and other areas perpetual low tide, although this would not be apparent to an observer they would just see the sea at the same level.

The Moon that isn't tidally locked would produce a tide, (as would the effects of the Sun) but being much further out, these tides would be very small.

It is unlikely that Earth could have two Moons in this fashion as they would cause gravitational disturbances to each other's orbits leading to unstable orbital patterns and eventually one being ejected or some form of impact.